# Marzipan in Italy - what brands should I look for?

Tags: food-and-drink, italy

Whenever I'm in Germany, one of the highlights for me is eating loads of Niederegger marzipan, and buying a few packs to enjoy the weeks after coming home. Unfortunately, I somehow forgot to stock up on my last trip, so it seems I'm in for a sad autumn wrt marzipan...

However. I'm off to Northern Italy in a couple of weeks. The Germans learned marzipan making from the Italians, didn't they? So I suppose someone in Italy also know how to make decent marzipan. What brands of Italian marzipan should I look for?

Comment: What are you after from the marzipan? Seems somewhat vauge a question at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's a bit vague. Hm. That's probably because I'm not sure what I'm looking for, exactly. Just some brand names to look out for, names generally considered high quality.

Comment: What makes this travel-related? How would a visitor choosing marzipan differ from a local?

Comment: @pnuts I'm skeptical of many of those questions, but the implication there at least is "I want to visit this place; how can I do that?" This question might be salvageable if honed, as they say, to a "laser-like focus." But if it's a question about how to judge good marzipan from bad, it's applicable anywhere, and is better answered by food experts than travel experts.